# Find matches of 2 items in 2 different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Hello good afternoon community. I have an Excel question

I have this table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEnD1.png)

I can't find a way to determine which is the combination that is repeated the most but in both directions.

I mean, with the function count.si.set I can count how many Italy vs Portugal there were (12) but it doesn't give me how many Italy vs Portugal + Portugal vs Italy there were (14)

What is the step that I am missing?

Comment: Couldn't you just do two `COUNTIFS()` added together? If col A is Country X, and Col B is Country Y + if Col A is Country Y and Col B is country X

Answer (score 0):

You can use the greater than operator to check which word comes first alphabetically. Eg, `IF(A1>A2,1,0)` will return a 1 if the word in Cell A2 is alphabetically *Earlier* than the word in Cell A1.

Use this in the "Enfrentamientos" column with the following formula:

```
IF(A1 < B1, A1 & " " & " " B1, B1 & " " & A1)
```

This cells output will be the words in A1 and B1 concatenated in alphabetical order, so your Argentina & Germany pairs will come out the same as your Germany & Argentina Pairs.
Copy that formula down to the lower rows so it applies to each pair

Hope this helped!

Comment: You should use code formatting in your answer